# Появление кнопки по времени видео с Youtube на Jquery

Tags: jquery, youtube

Нужно сделать, чтобы на странице, где расположено видео с Youtube. Как сделать, чтобы кнопка появлялась в заданое время от не загрузки страницы (delay()), а по времени проигрывания видео. Есть скрипт для JW Player, но этот плееер не тянет видео с Youtube, особенно трансляцию. Да ещё и требует наличие FLash

Есть такой инициализатор для видео Youtube, но как выбрать нужное время проигрывания?

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        videoId: 'Xa0Q0J5tOP0',
        playerVars: {
            color: 'white',
            playlist: 'taJ60kskkns,FG0fTKAqZ5g'
        },
        events: {
            onReady: initialize
        }
    });
}

function initialize() {

    // Update the controls on load
    updateTimerDisplay();
    updateProgressBar();

    // Clear any old interval.
    clearInterval(time_update_interval);

    // Start interval to update elapsed time display and
    // the elapsed part of the progress bar every second.
    time_update_interval = setInterval(function () {
        updateTimerDisplay();
        updateProgressBar();
    }, 1000)

}
$('#current-time').text(formatTime( player.getCurrentTime() ));
```

Я предположил такое продолжение:

```
var showTime = $('#current-time').text(formatTime(player.getCurrentTime()));
if (showTime >= 3000) { // Если текущее время проигрывателя больше, либо равно нужного числа
$('#my_button').fadeIn(500);}
```

Но он не срабатывает

Comment: а что showTime  возвращает Вам? Он может стркоу вернуть, нужно в parseInt обернуть

Comment: Консоль вообще выдает formatTime is not defined

Comment: Вы посмотрите что Вам даёт player.getCurrentTime()

Comment: Консоль пишет вообще player is undefined

Comment: Значит у Вас player не выдает время

Comment: Что делать? Как быть? Задача неразрешима? )))